# How can i find the closest image using input type hidden in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i find the closest image using input type hidden.

i want to find `<div class="wrap_col td4 participantstatus">`

and change the image how can i find it using the closest input type hidden?

this is my code:

```
$("input[value='closest_img']").find(".participantstatus img").attr("src","/pc/images/mute.png");
```

this is my code:

```
 <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body">
     <div class="wrap_col td1">
     <input type="hidden" name="hiddenuid" value="closest_img">
     <div class="wrap_col td2">1</div>
     <div class="wrap_col td3">2</div>
     <div class="wrap_col td4 participantstatus"><img style="vertical-align: middle" src="/pc/images/dissable.png"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.participantstatus` is not a descendants of `input` element, find it using [`.sibling()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and after that using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) as `img` is a child of `.participantstatus` element:

```
$("input[value='closest_img']").siblings(".participantstatus").find('img').attr("src","/pc/images/mute.png");
```

If `.participantstatus` located next to input element, you can find it using [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/) after all like so:

```
$("input[value='closest_img']").nextAll(".participantstatus").find('img').attr("src","/pc/images/mute.png");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/812fnfL3/)

Comment: Thanks @NorlihazmeyGhazali